declarativeNetRequest rule condition - how to trigger before Chrome interprets as a search
I'm building a Chrome extension, manifest version 3, and grappling with declarativeNetRequest.
Desired behavior:

User types in something like "go/blah" in their Chrome URL bar
The pattern "go/*" triggers my Chrome extension, which can then process "blah" and do something with it

I currently have this working by putting this code in a service worker script:
const EXT_PAGE = chrome.runtime.getURL('/redirect.html');
const RULES = [{
  id: 1,
  action: {
    type: 'redirect',
    redirect: { regexSubstitution: EXT_PAGE + '#\\0' },
  },
  condition: {
    regexFilter: '^https?:\/\/.+google.com\/[^q]*q\=go%2F.*',
    resourceTypes: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame'],
  },
}];
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
  removeRuleIds: RULES.map(r => r.id),
  addRules: RULES,
});

What this does is that when a user types in "go/blah" into their browser, Chrome interprets it as a Google search for "go/blah", so proceeds to the Google search results page. My rule then catches it and the rest of my logic fires from there.
That's fine, but what I'm wondering is whether it's possible for my rule to catch the url before Google interprets it as a Google search?
